# sans serif with cfr-lm

Tags: sans-serif, cfr-lm

The `cfr-lm` package enables old style numerals for Latin Modern.
It is based on the `nfssext-cfr` package that defines the `\lnstyle` macro switching back to lining numerals. Usually I switch to sans serif by using `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` but in this case the text affected by `\lnstyle` is not switched to sans serif.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{nfssext-cfr} % defines \lnstyle, does not cause problems on its own
\usepackage{cfr-lm} % switches to Latin Modern with old style numerals
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} % switch to sans serif
% \renewcommand{\lnstyle}{\fontfamily{clm2s}\selectfont} % hard coded fix    
\begin{document}
test 123 % sans serif old style numerals
\lnstyle test 123 % should be sans serif lining numerals
\end{document}
```

Is this behavior a bug or am I making a mistake?

Comment: Probably neither. `\lnstyle` is subtractive, like `\regstyle`, which the manual starts to explain as: "A - indicates that the macro will attempt to subtract from the current font’s family name, series or shape." What that means, I don't know enough yet. The package works cumulatively on font features, so it would be worthwhile noticing also: "The actual effect of any macro depends on any changes made to the defaults for various font features, the current font and, of course, what is available." `\lnstyle` works at the font family level, as I understand. Unrelated: why not use `\osstyle`?

Comment: Thanks to your comment I have notices that there is a second lining figures macro `\lstyle`. This one seems to do what I am looking for. But honestly I have trouble understanding the difference between these two commands.

Comment: Note that, if you can use `fontspec`, it supports `\liningnums` and `\oldstylenums` commands that invoke the OpenType font features.

Answer (score 1):

A picture may help.

[image: fonts]

And that's just the `\rmfamily` upright shape. Bold, italics, bolditalics, small caps. Multiply by `\sffamily` and `\ttfamily`... And not all font features are going to exist in all permutations, so the "nearest" one is searched for...

This is the tip-of-the-iceberg of the complexity required when dealing with the old 7-bit and 8-bit fonts.

As I understand it, in the legacy-font world, to activate a font feature or deactivate one, the `nfssext-cfr` package employs a set of switches which cumulatively add to, or subtract from, what was previously switched on/off upstream. So the effect of a switch depends heavily on the context.

The package assumes (1) that the font files are named using the Berry scheme; (2) that NFSS letter codes are being used, like `j` and `2` in the illustration; and (3) that the default font settings have not been re-defined.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm} % calls nfssext-cfr
\newcommand\testtext{123,456,789 \fontname\font }

\begin{document}
%=======================
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Setting & Sample + font used & Code\\
\hline Package Default & \testtext& \\
+j & \ostyle\testtext& \verb|\ostyle|\\
-j & \lstyle\testtext& \verb|\lstyle|\\
+2 & \pstyle\testtext& \verb|\pstyle|\\
-2 & \tstyle\testtext& \verb|\tstyle|\\
+j+2 & \postyle\testtext& \verb|\postyle|\\
-j-2 & \tlstyle\testtext& \verb|\tlstyle|\\
+j-2 & \tostyle\testtext& \verb|\tostyle|\\
-j+2 & \plstyle\testtext& \verb|\plstyle|\\
No style & \regstyle\testtext& \verb|\regstyle|\\
No style +j & \regstyle\ostyle\testtext& \verb|\regstyle\ostyle|\\
No style +2 & \regstyle\pstyle\testtext& \verb|\regstyle\pstyle|\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

*ADDED*

The following MWE shows the three font families, in normal, bold, bolditalics, italics, small caps, and small caps bold; and the nearest font selected where the font feature was not available.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm} % calls nfssext-cfr
\newcommand\testtext{123,456,789 \fontname\font }
\newcommand\tv[1]{\regstyle\normalfont\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\newcommand\thesample[1]{%
\noindent #1

\begin{tabular}{lll}
Setting & Sample + font used & Code\\
\hline Package Default & \testtext& \\
+j & \ostyle\testtext& \tv{ostyle}\\
-j & \lstyle\testtext& \tv{lstyle}\\
+2 & \pstyle\testtext& \tv{pstyle}\\
-2 & \tstyle\testtext& \tv{tstyle}\\
+j+2 & \postyle\testtext& \tv{postyle}\\
-j-2 & \tlstyle\testtext& \tv{tlstyle}\\
+j-2 & \tostyle\testtext& \tv{tostyle}\\
-j+2 & \plstyle\testtext& \tv{plstyle}\\
No style & \regstyle\testtext& \tv{regstyle}\\
No style +j & \regstyle\ostyle\testtext& \tv{regstyle}\tv{ostyle}\\
No style +2 & \regstyle\pstyle\testtext& \tv{regstyle}\tv{pstyle}\\
\end{tabular}
\par\bigskip
}
\begin{document}
%=======================
\rmfamily
\thesample{rmfamily normal}

\bfseries
\thesample{rmfamily bold}

\itshape
\thesample{rmfamily bold italics}


\mdseries
\thesample{rmfamily italics}

\upshape
\scshape
\thesample{rmfamily small caps}

\bfseries
\thesample{rmfamily small caps bold}
\upshape
\mdseries


%=======================
\sffamily
\thesample{sffamily normal}

\bfseries
\thesample{sffamily bold}

\itshape
\thesample{sffamily bold italics}


\mdseries
\thesample{sffamily italics}

\upshape
\scshape
\thesample{sffamily small caps}

\bfseries
\thesample{sffamily small caps bold}
\upshape
\mdseries



%=======================
\ttfamily
\thesample{ttfamily normal}

\bfseries
\thesample{ttfamily bold}

\itshape
\thesample{ttfamily bold italics}


\mdseries
\thesample{ttfamily italics}

\upshape
\scshape
\thesample{ttfamily small caps}

\bfseries
\thesample{ttfamily small caps bold}
\upshape
\mdseries


\end{document}
```